# Dummy name of class created by a function appears to still exist after function return -python

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

Say I make a class `Hello` with a method that calls `Hello`. If I assign the class to `Hello2` and `del Hello`, then that method will raise an exception indicating that it couldn't find the name `Hello`.

On the other hand, say I run a function that makes a class `dummyName` with a method that calls `dummyName` and assign the returned class to `Bye`. If I assign the class to `Bye2` and `del Bye`, then that method still runs. It appears as if the variable `dummyName` still exists. If it does, where is its namespace, and how is it decided what type of object keeps a cryptic reference after a function returns?

EDIT: A commenter suggested that the class is referenced by a closure. Indeed, a FUNCTION has a `__closure__` attribute, and if the function was nested in another function, the `__closure__` attribute references a tuple of `cell` objects, each of which has a `cell_contents` attribute referencing an object created in the outer function. However, the class `Bye2` does not have a `__closure__` attribute, so the question still stands.

```
def make_Bye():
    class dummyName:
        word = 'bye'
        def talk(self):
            return dummyName.word
    return dummyName

Bye = make_Bye()

class Hello:
    word = 'hello'
    def talk(self):
        return Hello.word

print('1.', Bye.talk(None)) # 1. bye
print('2.', Hello.talk(None)) # 2. hello

# now let's give these classes new names and delete the old names
Hello2 = Hello
del Hello
Bye2 = Bye
del Bye

print('3.', Bye2.talk(None)) # 3. bye
print('4.', Hello2.talk(None)) # NameError: name 'Hello' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amadan was in fact very close. The class originally assigned to `dummyName` was indeed stored in a `__closure__`, but not in the function `make_Bye` and certainly not in the class it returns. It was in the `talk` method. When the `talk` method was defined, it uses the variable `dummyName`, and that variable belongs to the scope of `make_Bye`. Therefore, the class assigned to `dummyName` gets stored in `talk.__closure__` for `talk` to use later. Rename the class all you like, and `talk` will still use its `closure` to access the class.

On the other hand, the `Hello` class's `talk` accesses the variable `Hello`, which belongs to the global namespace. Delete that global variable, and `talk` will run into a NameError.

Answer (score 3):

> It appears as if the variable dummyName still exists.

You are correct.

> If it does, where is its namespace

`dummyName` is not directly accessible any more: it is in [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) of `make_Bye`.

```
Bye2.__qualname__
# => make_Bye.<locals>.dummyName`
```

On the other hand, `Hello2` is:

```
Hello2.__qualname__
# => Hello
```

which cannot be found any more.

**EDIT:** This is incorrect; it is not in the closure. As I said in the comment, closure is a mechanism that allows a function access to variables outside it; here a value is exported from the function. Truth be told, I am less surprised by the fact that `Bye2` works than by the fact that `Hello2` does not.

Comment: looking up closures and by fiddling with a bit more code, I found that a nested function has a `__closure__` attribute containing cell objects that reference objects outside the nested function's scope. A recursive function would containing a cell object referencing itself, and similar to my example, renaming the function does not raise a NameError when run because of that reference. However, I can't find a `__closure__` attribute in a nested class. Does it have a different mechanism from functions?

Comment: Closures involve local variables being captured to be used during a function execution as well as in the surrounding context. Classes are not executable (more precisely, a Python class can be made callable by defining `__call__`, but it is still the function doing the executing), so the concept of closure does not apply to classes.

Comment: if so, then where does `dummyName` stay? `repr` represents `Bye2` as `__main__.make_Bye.<locals>.dummyName` as it would if Bye2 were a nested function, but Bye2 has no `__closure__`. `makeBye.__closure__` is `None` like any unnested function.

Comment: It seems you are right, I seem I was mistaken. Closure captures variables in the outer context for use inside the function. This is a variable from inside the function that was exported out of it. I will delete the answer.

Comment: I suppose I should unselect it so people can have a chance to answer this, but I would rather you did not delete it, as other people would likely also presume a nested class uses the same mechanism as a nested function. Instead, you could edit your answer to indicate to others not to make the same error.